# Filter Json data in angularjs Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am creating web app using angular js. I have array of json object. I need the data who have status active and pending.here is my array:

```
$scope.response =  staticRoutes : [
    {'id':1,'name':'ABC 1','subnet':'SUB 101','gateway':'GATE 101','status':'Active'},
    {'id':2,'name':'ABC 2','subnet':'SUB 102','gateway':'GATE 102','status':'In Active'},
    {'id':3,'name':'ABC 1','subnet':'SUB 101','gateway':'GATE 101','status':'Active'},
    {'id':4,'name':'ABC 2','subnet':'SUB 102','gateway':'GATE 102','status':'In Active'},
    {'id':5,'name':'ABC 1','subnet':'SUB 101','gateway':'GATE 101','status':'Active'},
    {'id':6,'name':'ABC 2','subnet':'SUB 102','gateway':'GATE 102','status':'In Active'},
    {'id':7,'name':'ABC 1','subnet':'SUB 101','gateway':'GATE 101','status':'Active'},
    {'id':8,'name':'ABC 2','subnet':'SUB 102','gateway':'GATE 102','status':'In Active'},
    {'id':9,'name':'ABC 1','subnet':'SUB 101','gateway':'GATE 101','status':'Active'},
    {'id':10,'name':'ABC 2','subnet':'SUB 102','gateway':'GATE 102','status':'In Active'},
    {'id':11,'name':'ABC 1','subnet':'SUB 101','gateway':'GATE 101','status':'Active'},
    {'id':12,'name':'ABC 2','subnet':'SUB 102','gateway':'GATE 102','status':'In Active'},
    {'id':13,'name':'ABC 3','subnet':'SUB 103','gateway':'GATE 103','status':'Pending'}
]
```

Comment: try this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20530637/filter-json-data-with-angularjs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var filterdata = [];
        angular.forEach($scope.response,function(value,key){
            if(value.status == "active" || value.status == "pending")
            {
                filterdata.push(value);

            }   
        })
        console.log(filterFlows)
```

Answer (score 1):

For a simple filter, `Underscore` really isn't needed, unless you're targeting older browsers. All semi modern browsers support `Array.prototype.filter()`. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for information on how to use it and browser support.

Use it like this:

```
 var filteredArray = $scope.response.filter(function(response){
     return response.status === 'Active' || response.status === 'Pending'
 });
```

Comment: if i do this with underscoreJs is it wrong? I have used underscoreJS i my application and i found it very useful.

Comment: No definitely not wrong! However for this simple task, you don't need it explicitly. It's an added dependency that's mostly redundant for this case. If you're already using Underscore, because you need it for different cases, by all means go ahead. But I wouldn't add a dependency to something when it can be done just as easily without :)

Comment: yeah thanks for explanation @luka i have big application thats why i am using it. It reduces the plenty of code.

Comment: It shows me empty array. when i console.log(filteredArray )

Comment: Then maybe ` $scope.response` isn't filled yet? I see you also have `staticRoutes` as a name in there, you could try replacing  `$scope.response` with `staticRoutes`. It's not quite clear from your code.

Answer (score 0):

[UnderscoreJs](http://underscorejs.org/) is very useful in these type of calculation

**Solution** -

```
 var filteredData = _.filter($scope.response,function(response){
      return response.status === 'Active' || response.status === 'Pending'
 });
```

*filteredData* will be an array of filtered contents.

Comment: This won't work, because `response` isn't defined as a parameter of your anonymous function.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your array is called `staticRoutes`, you could do

```
$scope.response = staticRoutes.filter(function(item){
    return item.status.toLowerCase() === 'active' || item.status.toLowerCase() === 'pending';
});
```